# Mutual fund tax exemption SBI

Tags: taxes, india, mutual-funds

I have a SIP investment with SBI TECHNOLOGY OPPORTUNITIES FUND Regular growth. Can I show this investment for tax exemption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a regular scheme and is not eligible for tax rebate/deduction.

You need to invest in schemes that are ELSS with lock-in of 3 years for tax deduction

Comment: Is one time investment in ELSS fund eligible for tax exemption ?

Comment: @rdj7 Yes it is for that year.